# Problems with iframes on cordova apps

Tags: cordova, iframe, phonegap, whitelist

I'm developing an app with cordova and no matter what, the youtube iframe doesn't loads whenever I run the app on Android. I've tried several things I've seen here and in other websites such as making changes to the whitelist, adding parameters to the meta tag "Content-Security-Policy", making changes on the config file... nothing works for me. I'm getting a little frustrated with this issue. I know this problem is related to cordova not letting other websites to show data on the app for security purposes but I can't figure out how to make it work. If someone could help me out on this I'll be very thankfull.

this is my Content-Security-Policy meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" script-src='unsafe-inline'>
```

This is my config file

```
    <content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*youtube.com/*"/>
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-browsersync" spec="^1.1.0" />
```

The config file has the default lines but as I said before, I've tried everything I've founded. HELP!

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, after re-installing the Whitelist plugin and letting the confing as it is, the problem got solved and now the youtube iframe is ok. After reading in a few forums and articles I believe that the solition to the problem is this line on the config file:

```
<allow-navigation href="https://*youtube.com/*"/>
```